# intellij : "search results are not loaded check the internet connection"

Tags: intellij-idea, marketplace

Using Intelliji for Java, I'm trying to get cucumber plugin, so i go to the file dropdown menu and go to settings menu and go to plugins. I type in cucumber in the plugins search bar. But nothing is found in the search results.
The message given is " search results are not loaded check the internet connection "
I also get " marketplace plugins are not loaded. Check the internet connection and >refresh< "

My internet connection is fine. I've already downloaded a load of dependancies using maven via intellij. the refresh button doesn't help. Why does intellij think the problem is no internet connection? How do I get intellij to find plugins?

Answer (score 24):

I needed to set up a proxy under Appearance & Behavior Settings, System Settings, HTTP Proxy. I selected auto detect proxy settings. After this I was able to see plugins in the marketplace window.

Comment: Please make sure that you also unchecked the `Automatic proxy configuration URL` box

Comment: This isn't working with the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: This solution works well with intellij idea community edition 2022.1.1

Comment: Should be accepted, I think it's my workplace's strange internal network set up, this resolved the issue!

Answer (score 11):

For me I was able to get the marketplace working when I went to
Configure>Settings>HTTP Proxy Settings> Auto-detect proxy settings>Automatic Proxy configuration URL: https://plugins.jetbrains.com

Actually it seems to be working even without the Automatic Proxy configuration URL disabled

Answer (score 4):

The changes of the settings work for me:

[image]

Comment: In my case I set up Manual proxy configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the comments on this [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004275380-Marketplace-Plugins-are-not-loaded?page=1#community_comment_360000773459), I made the following changes:

1. Enabled Auto-detect proxy settings under Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy.
2. Removed the below flag under the Help > Custom VM Options.

> -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false

Restarted Intellij after making these changes. Made these changes on Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.3

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you can try.
I will start with what worked for me!

1. I felt my IP was blocking the plugins, I enabled the VPN and it worked!
2. for some version IntelliJ looks for plugins using HTTP protocol instead of 
   HTTPS, so add the following lines 
   IntelliJ bin folder-> idea.properties, 
   idea.plugins.host=https://plugins.jetbrains.com
3. try disabling the SNIExtension, Help->Edit Custom VM options
   Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false

Answer (score 2):

Such questions we should refer to the log of IDEA at first.
visit the menu Help ~> Show Log in Exporer, will open the directory of log,

For me,the log file is  C:\Users\lawev\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\log\idea.log.
open the file we can find such contenet

```
2020-09-10 12:39:16,795 [ 158219]   INFO - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - failed to load plugin descriptions from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea: SSL error probably caused by disabled SNI
```

Now I see ,visit the menu Help ~> Edit Custom VM Options, check or add this line

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=true
```

now it's ok!

my envirment is win10 1909,Intellij UI 2020.1

Comment: (close and open)/restart the IDE to apply the setting

Answer (score 1):

Starting IntelliJ (2019.2.1) on Windows 10 64-bit in Admin mode fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my goland settings somehow get corrputs, i delete the folder `~/.GoLand2019.2`, and restart goland, then the marketplace works.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it happen because your internet service provider/ISP block https://plugins.jetbrains.com. There is 2 ways i solve it:

1. Before i use Sm'rtfren SIM Card Phone(from my country) provider which is can not load marketplace plugin. Then i switch to Tr'e SIM Card Phone provider and it works!
2. You can use UrbanVPN Desktop software, i use windows version. it will change  ISP IP and then it works!

Answer (score -1):

I encounter the similar problem in Android Studio when I want to install the Flutter& Dart plugins .

For me,I install Shadowsocks vpn proxy(https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks) in my computer.Then I change the Shadowsocks vpn proxy to global mode. After this I was able to see plugins in the marketplace window.Hope it can help you